# How can I convert quick order image to css in Magento 2?

Tags: css, design, icon

I have this icon
[image]

I wanna convert in css this icon.
This is below code I implemented but could not success.Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dot {
  height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rectangle {
  border:2px solid #000;
width:30px;
height:30px;
  border-radius: 2px;
   display: inline-block;
}
.small-rectangle {
  border:2px solid #000;
width:30px;
height:30px;
  border-radius: 2px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-bottom:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>Round Dots / Circles</h1>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="small-rectangle"></span>
  <span class="rectangle"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-rec {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.main-rec::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(-2px, -100%);
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.half-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 16px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, 5px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-rec">
  <div class="top-rec">
  </div>
  <div class="half-circle"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<i class="gg-shopping-bag"></i>
```

Style

```
 .gg-shopping-bag {
 transform: scale(var(--ggs,1))
}

.gg-shopping-bag,
.gg-shopping-bag::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-radius: 3px
}

.gg-shopping-bag::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 height: 6px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
 border-top: 0;
 top: 2px;
 left: 3px
} 

.gg-shopping-bag::before {
     content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 0;
    top: -6px;
    left: -2px;
    clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 90% 0%, 100% 74%, 0% 70%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create icon in this site:- https://icomoon.io/

see the how can create icon :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccjc82xEe4k&ab_channel=MohanMadheshwaran

Then after how to call icon css in our theme

app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/default/web/css/fonts.css

app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/default//Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/fonts.css"/> 
     </head>
</page>
```

You can add your icon in your html file as per the fonts.css icon name

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <i class="quick-order-icon"></i>   
</div>
```